# The implementation of red-black trees gives problems inserting a duplicate number

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, red-black-tree

I'm implementing a red-black tree. But I keep getting error messages when the same number is entered multiple times (like the two 5's in "numbers").

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, color="RED"):
        """
        Node class represents a node in the Red-Black Tree.

        Args:
            key: The key value of the node.
            color: The color of the node (RED or BLACK).

        Attributes:
            key: The key value of the node.
            parent: The parent node.
            left: The left child node.
            right: The right child node.
            color: The color of the node (RED or BLACK).
        """
        self.key = key
        self.parent = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.color = color


class RedBlackTree:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        RedBlackTree class represents a Red-Black Tree.

        Attributes:
            NIL: The sentinel node representing a null leaf node.
            root: The root node of the Red-Black Tree.
        """
        self.NIL = Node(None, color="BLACK")
        self.root = self.NIL

    def insert(self, key):
        """
        Inserts a new node with the given key into the Red-Black Tree.

        Args:
            key: The key value of the node to be inserted.
        """
        new_node = Node(key)
        new_node.left = self.NIL
        new_node.right = self.NIL

        parent = None
        current = self.root

        while current != self.NIL:
            parent = current
            if key < current.key:
                current = current.left
            else:
                current = current.right

        new_node.parent = parent

        if parent is None:
            self.root = new_node
        elif key < parent.key:
            parent.left = new_node
        else:
            parent.right = new_node

        self._insert_fixup(new_node)

    def _insert_fixup(self, node):
        """
        Fixes the Red-Black Tree properties after node insertion.

        Args:
            node: The newly inserted node.
        """
        while node != self.root and node.parent.color == "RED":
            if node.parent == node.parent.parent.left:
                uncle = node.parent.parent.right
                if uncle.color == "RED":
                    node.parent.color = "BLACK"
                    uncle.color = "BLACK"
                    node.parent.parent.color = "RED"
                    node = node.parent.parent
                else:
                    if node == node.parent.right:
                        node = node.parent
                        self._left_rotate(node)
                    node.parent.color = "BLACK"
                    node.parent.parent.color = "RED"
                    self._right_rotate(node.parent.parent)
            else:
                uncle = node.parent.parent.left
                if uncle.color == "RED":
                    node.parent.color = "BLACK"
                    uncle.color = "BLACK"
                    node.parent.parent.color = "RED"
                    node = node.parent.parent
                else:
                    if node == node.parent.left:
                        node = node.parent
                        self._right_rotate(node)
                    node.parent.color = "BLACK"
                    node.parent.parent.color = "RED"
                    self._left_rotate(node.parent.parent)

        self.root.color = "BLACK"

    def _left_rotate(self, node):
        """
        Performs a left rotation on the given node.

        Args:
            node: The node to perform the left rotation on.
        """
        right_child = node.right
        node.right = right_child.left
        if right_child.left != self.NIL:
            right_child.left.parent = node
        right_child.parent = node.parent
        if node.parent == self.NIL:
            self.root = right_child
        elif node == node.parent.left:
            node.parent.left = right_child
        else:
            node.parent.right = right_child
        right_child.left = node
        node.parent = right_child

    def _right_rotate(self, node):
        """
        Performs a right rotation on the given node.

        Args:
            node: The node to perform the right rotation on.
        """
        if node is None or node.left is None:
            return

        left_child = node.left
        node.left = left_child.right
        if left_child.right != self.NIL:
            left_child.right.parent = node
        left_child.parent = node.parent
        if node.parent == self.NIL:
            self.root = left_child
        elif node == node.parent.left:
            node.parent.left = left_child
        else:
            node.parent.right = left_child

        left_child.right = node
        node.parent = left_child
        node.left.parent = node

    def inorder_traversal(self):
        """Performs an inorder traversal of the Red-Black Tree."""
        self._inorder_recursive(self.root)

    def _inorder_recursive(self, node):
        """
        Performs an inorder traversal of the Red-Black Tree recursively.

        Args:
            node: The current node in the traversal.
        """
        if node != self.NIL:
            self._inorder_recursive(node.left)
            print(node.key, end=" ")
            self._inorder_recursive(node.right)

    def search(self, key):
        """
        Searches for a node with the given key in the Red-Black Tree.

        Args:
            key: The key value to search for.

        Returns:
            The node with the given key if found, None otherwise.
        """
        return self._search_recursive(self.root, key)

    def _search_recursive(self, node, key):
        """
        Searches for a node with the given key in the Red-Black Tree recursively.

        Args:
            node: The current node in the search.
            key: The key value to search for.

        Returns:
            The node with the given key if found, None otherwise.
        """
        if node == self.NIL or key == node.key:
            return node
        if key < node.key:
            if node.left != self.NIL:
                return self._search_recursive(node.left, key)
        else:
            if node.right != self.NIL:
                return self._search_recursive(node.right, key)
        return None


rbt = RedBlackTree()

numbers = [10, 5, 5, 3, 7, 13, 18, 1, 6, 11, 14, 17, 19]

for number in numbers:
    rbt.insert(number)

print("Red-Black Tree (inorder traversal):")
rbt.inorder_traversal()

to_search = [6, 12, 321]

print("\n")
for number in to_search:
    if rbt.search(number):
        print(f"The number {number} was found in the Red-Black Tree.")
    else:
        print(f"--The number {number} was not found in the Red-Black Tree--")
```

I've made several small tweaks, but none of them solve the problem, does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/Alberi_rosso_neri", line 209, in <module>
    rbt.insert(number)
  File "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/Alberi_rosso_neri", line 66, in insert
    self._insert_fixup(new_node)
  File "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/Alberi_rosso_neri", line 89, in _insert_fixup
    self._right_rotate(node.parent.parent)
  File "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/Alberi_rosso_neri", line 145, in _right_rotate
    elif node == node.parent.left:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'
```

I realize it's probably a logic error, but I can't figure out where it is and how to fix it. The code must be able to receive multiple equal numbers.
Any idea or solution?

Comment: In this code: `if parent is None: self.root = new_node` do you also need to set `self.root.parent = self.NIL` ?

Comment: This should be solved by running your code with a debugger, setting breakpoints, inspecting variables. What are the results of your debugging session?

Comment: No, it is not necessary to set self.root.parent = self.NIL in the code.
In the code, when parent is None, it means that the tree is empty and the new node being inserted becomes the root node.

Comment: OK - then the problem is that line 145 (which throws the error) assumes that `node.parent` is not None, when in some situations it is None.